Zipping csv files via Python from S3
I'm trying to create class where we get data from a table and we then split into chunks or rows and then save those partitioned data into individual csv files which contains 1Million rows each. We are currently using pyspark here. The problem now lies where I successfully placed saved those files in the output_path but the method zip_csv_files I created seems to be not working. We are using ofs path like ofs://oc/ectt do you think I should use different library for path in the zip_csv_files method?
script = spark.sql('''select status_date, sum(ros) as ros_all
                      from table_name
                      group by 1
                      order by 1''')
output_path = 'xxx'
file_name_prefix = 'marikina'
chunk_size = 1000000

saver = DataFrameChunkSaver(script, output_path, file_name_prefix, chunk_size)
saver.save_chunks()

Results:

Chunk 1 saved to xxx/marikina0.folder

Chunk 2 saved to xxx/marikina1.folder
saver.zip_csv_files()


Results:
Zipping CSV files to xxx/chunks.zip
Checking folder: xxx/marikina0.folder
Folder xxx/marikina0.folder does not exist or is not a directory. 
Stopping.

import os
import zipfile

class DataFrameChunkSaver:
    def __init__(self, df, output_path, file_name_prefix='karl', chunk_size=1000000):
        self.df = df
        self.output_path = output_path
        self.chunk_size = chunk_size
        self.file_name_prefix = file_name_prefix
        self.output_file_template = os.path.join(self.output_path, f"{self.file_name_prefix}{{}}.folder")
        self.zip_file_path = os.path.join(self.output_path, "chunks.zip")
        
        # Ensure the directory exists
        os.makedirs(self.output_path, exist_ok=True)
    
    def count_chunks(self):
        total_rows = self.df.count()
        return -(-total_rows // self.chunk_size)

    def repartition_df(self):
        num_chunks = self.count_chunks()
        return self.df.repartition(num_chunks)

    def save_chunks(self):
        repartitioned_df = self.repartition_df()
        num_chunks = self.count_chunks()
        
        for i in range(num_chunks):
            chunk_file_path = self.output_file_template.format(i)
            partition_df = repartitioned_df.filter(f"spark_partition_id() == {i}")
            partition_df.coalesce(1).write.csv(chunk_file_path, header=True)
            print(f"Chunk {i + 1} saved to {chunk_file_path}")

 def zip_csv_files(self):
        print(f"Zipping CSV files to {self.zip_file_path}")
        with zipfile.ZipFile(self.zip_file_path, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zipf:
            folder_index = 0
            while True:
                folder_path = self.output_file_template.format(folder_index)
                print(f"Checking folder: {folder_path}")
                if not os.path.exists(folder_path) or not os.path.isdir(folder_path):
                    print(f"Folder {folder_path} does not exist or is not a directory. Stopping.")
                    break  # Stop if the folder doesn't exist

                for filename in os.listdir(folder_path):
                    file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, filename)
                    if filename.endswith(".csv"):
                        print(f"Adding {file_path} to zip")
                        zipf.write(file_path, arcname=os.path.join(os.path.basename(folder_path), filename))
                    else:
                        print(f"Skipping non-CSV file: {filename}")

                folder_index += 1 

        print(f"All applicable CSV files zipped into {self.zip_file_path}")


the method zip_csv_files i created seems to be not working "Not working" is not a good description of the problem.  Please explain the actual results of this code, and explain how those results aren't what you expected.

Results shown above: “Zipping CSV files to xxx/chunks.zip Checking folder: xxx/marikina0.folder Folder xxx/marikina0.folder does not exist or is not a directory. Stopping.” Its not detecting the csv files inside the folder

The code assumes that xxx/marikina0.folder is a subdirectory of the current directory, but it is not.  The current directory is not necessarily the same directory  as the python script itself.  You can see the actual current directory with this bit of code import os; print(os.getcwd())
